# $lookup get "first" and combine addField + exclude fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection "Notes" which contains a reference to a question index in a nested array of questions in another collection called "Chapters".

I came up with an aggregation which works fine, but I would like to know if there is a chance to:

1. $lookup with a limit of 1, so that we don't need to add another aggregation stage just to get the "first" item from the lookup array result, and
2. To combine the last 3 stages (reduce the number of stages), where I am "picking" the particular question by index from the array of questions, then projecting it to a field "question", and excluding the "questions" field.
3. I would like to know if there is any performance benefit reducing number of aggregation stages. I don't know why I want to reduce or combine the stages, but have a feeling it should improve performance or at least be more elegant?

[Mongo Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w8dXU8pKfWV)

**The aggregation pipeline is like this:**

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chapters",
      let: {
        chapter_id: "$chapter"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$chapter_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            questions: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "chapter",
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      chapter: {
        $first: "$chapter",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      question: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$chapter.questions",
          "$question"
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "chapter.questions": 0,
    },
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

does this helps https://mongoplayground.net/p/QEGIFNvisNy?

I have reduced the lookup to limit only one record by passing limit stage to 1. also we need to unwind after lookup(though it has always one matched document in your case), then no need for first as we only have one matched document. rest of the stages are quite same.

Comment: I believe the $unwind that you have used vs $first that I have used is sort of doing the same thing here as I have only one matched document. I was looking to somehow reduce the number of stages, yours is the same. However, many thanks for your iteration, I appreciate it.